# Better way to return classes from corresponding strings

Tags: python, oop, eval

I'm  writing a fantasy programming language for a game. Part of what the interpreter does is converts the code (a string) into command objects. For example, the following code:

```
set var 1
```

creates a variable called var with the value of 1. In the interpreter, this creates a new instance of the `Set` command class. Currently, I have a list of if statements to create commands:

```
    if packet == "set":
        return commands.Set
    elif packet == "get":
        return commands.Get
    elif packet == "print":
        return commands.Print
    elif packet == "goto":
        return commands.Goto
    elif packet == "add":
        return commands.Add
```

But this is a real pain when adding new commands. I have to add the command class, add it to a list of syntax, and add it to a table here.

I realized that `eval` could help me here, but I know that is looked down upon.

```
return eval("commands." + packet.capitalize())
```

Is there a better way to do this, or is `eval` okay in this usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
return getattr(commands, packet.capitalize())
```